# MySprite isn't defined, how do i define it?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to start to create a dungeon Role Playing Game. (like rogue)

```
tiles = list()
for y in range(0,45):
    for x in range(0,80):
        tiles.append(8)
text = MySprite()
text.load("ascii8*12.png", 8, 12, 32)
```

For some reason, there's a syntax error saying that `MySprite` is not defined.
How do I define it? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you need to import it?  Also, to be technical, it is a `NameError`, not a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: no, importing didnt help. :/

Comment: @user3146817 The error says you haven't defined `MySprite`, so have you or have you not defined it? `MySprite` probably would have to be a class defined somewhere as `class MySprite: [...]` by yourself. The sprite class from pygame is called `pygame.sprite.Sprite`, not `MySprite`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have for loading my sprites and then rendering them

`g` is a class i use for storing globals, `images` is the list i use for storing the sprites, but they are stored as, like an instance, I don't what to call it but you can see from the code how I mean.

```
g.images.append(pygame.image.load('images/1.bmp'))

img1 = g.images[0]

g.DISPLAYSURF.blit(img1, (x,y))
```

What is your `MySprite()` exactly?

Hope this helps

PS: I am creating an rpg too, I've made a lot of progress, if you have any more questions about creating an RPG game ask meh :D

Comment: Awesome, happy 2 help. If you want some source code for my game u can find it here: http://pastebin.com/gMKr5SeS

Please keep in mind this is not how you should program, I'm an amateur XD

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame
text = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
text.image = pygame.image.load("ascii8*12.png").convert()
```

We don't know what is your MySprite class. This the way to create a sprite using a pygame sprite class.